# PHP fopen() work incorrect

Tags: php, function, fopen

I try to open a file but output of file is not correct,because output is half-part of data in a file. I don't know solutions to resolve this problem

```
  <?php
    $handle = fopen("data/weather.arff", "r");
            while ($buffer = fgetc($handle)) {
                $result .= $buffer;
            }
    echo $result;
  ?>
```

Comment: What does `weather.arff` look like?

Comment: Why not use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)? Also, why do you have spaces in your opening and closing tags

Comment: Also , consider writing your loop condition like: `while (false !== ($char = fgetc($fp))) {` as recommended by the php manual due to possibility of returned non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE

Comment: `weather.arff` look like text file

Comment: @php_nub_qq thank for your suggestion,I get correctly output

Comment: @php_nub_qq: $result was probably a test, and weather.arff might have been too big of a file for php to handle, so he decided to load it in parts.

Answer (score 1):

`while ($buffer = fgetc($handle)) {` could evaluate to false if you get a NULL char or a numeric zero. To avoid this, use a strict type compare such as `while (($char = fgetc($fp))  !== false) {` to ensure that you do not evaluate these other characters to false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Why I couldn't comment.(maybe lack of reputation). Have you used the "b" binary mode?! 
Like this:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "rb");
$contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);
?>
```

Source [function.fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)